# How to fetch FIRST row when there are same value for column in case of finding MIN value (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, min

In My table ,

One column has following values :

```
Row Column
 1   90
 2   95
 3   99
 4   90
 5   92
 6   90
```

Now I want to fetch `min value` for above column but fetch `top row` if there are more than one row which have `same minimum value`. How can I do this ?

As illustrated in above example : I want to min value(90) but first row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MIN is also the one that will sort first in ORDER. So simply specify the order you want and take first one:

```
WHERE Column is NOT NULL
ORDER BY Column, Row LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

use this query `select Row, min(column) from your_table  order by Row desc  limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the records in the same order of rows inserted, you can just use:

```
select Row, min(Column) from my_table group by Column;
```

If you want to fetch sorted rows as well:

```
select Row, min(Column) from my_table group by Column order by column, row;
```

And if you are looking only first row of the results, just append the query with `limit 1`;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM m_test WHERE row IN (
SELECT row FROM m_test b
WHERE b.column_cnt IN (SELECT min(a.column_cnt) FROM m_test a)) 
ORDER BY row ASC